# about will tense

Tags: passive-voice

Is the following sentence passive or not?

**You will be ready to go**.

**If yes**, why doesn't the **ready** word in the past participle form?

**If not**, why doesn't the **ready** word come with -ing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not passive. The _be_ is the auxiliary verb for the predicate adjective _ready_.

Comment: Active voice: *You will be happy to know. ...sorry to hear. ...hungry after those tiny portions*. Passive: *You will be fired for that*. Neutral: *The subject is closed. The door is stuck forever*.

Comment: *Ready* doesn't have *-ing* because it's just an adjective, like in "The house will be red."